# How to get id of an image of a clicked cardview from view element

Tags: java, android

In my layout applications I have a card view where each card contains a representations of an application. 
In each card there are: the name of an applications, a description and his icon.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterForCard.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.iv.setImageDrawable(myCards.get(position).getIcon());
        holder.titleView.setText(myCards.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.descView.setText(myCards.get(position).getInfo());

        holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.cv.getContext(), "Cliccked card: "+(holder.titleView.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Context context = v.getContext();

                Intent i = new Intent(context,DetailsAppActivity.class);
                //First Convert Image into Byte Array
                // and then pass into Intent and in next activity
                // get byte array from Bundle and Convert into Image(Bitmap) and set into ImageView
                // holder.iv.getId_ 2131296339 v.getId_ 2131296348.
                //
                int id1 = holder.iv.getId();
                int id2 = v.getId();
                int id3 = R.id.iconView;
                System.out.println("id1_ "+id1);
                System.out.println("id2_ "+id2);
                System.out.println("id3_ "+id3);

                Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(v.getResources(),id1);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                System.out.println("bitmap is null ? "+(btm==null));
                btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                i.putExtra("title", ""+holder.titleView.getText());
                i.putExtra("title", ""+holder.titleView.getText());
                i.putExtra("icon",byteArray);

                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
```

I want pass the three date to my DetailsActivity, but i have the follow error:

```
    id1_ 2131296339
    id2_ 2131296348
    id3_ 2131296339
    bitmap is null ? true
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.salvatorefiorilla.systemmonitor, PID: 6151
                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                          at com.salvatorefiorilla.systemmonitor.AdapterForCard$1.onClick(AdapterForCard.java:90)
                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

How to set id correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2**

As you told that you don't have resource id. You have application package, and have to get application icon, so you can pass package name of that app. And in next activity just get application icon.

**Important Edit**

I did not notice that you are using **Drawable** object instead of using an int id. There is no need to store drawable objects in List. So do the following.

- First change type of **`icon`** as **`int`** (Resource id).

`list.setIconId(R.drawable.ic_launcher)`

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), myCards.get(position).getIconId());`

- set ImageView image by below method.
- Old solution is also edited for same.

`holder.iv.setImageResource(myCards.get(position).getIconId());`

#### Solution

Just change `holder.iv.getId();` with `myCards.get(position).getIconId()`

```
Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(v.getResources(),myCards.get(position).getIconId());
```

**Reason of crash**

Because `holder.iv.getId()` returns you `ImageView` id **NOT** drawable resource id.

#### Suggestion (must use)

Pass resource id instead of passing bitmap array. There is no need to pass byte array of bitmap.

```
i.putExtra("icon",myCards.get(position).getIconId());
```

in next activity

```
imageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("icon",0));
```

**Isn't it simple :)**

Comment: Thanks, but getIcon() for some reasons method returns a Drawable, and have to remains so, now i need to find id from it ! Do you know how to get it?

Comment: I did not see that you are using drawable object , why you are saving drawable. Just use resource id.

Comment: Because I do not have the resource id. I get the Drawable object from methods like
Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon (packageName).
So luckily I can always pass the packageName.

Comment: Yes, you got it. Pass package name, and get its icon in next activity.

Answer (score 0):

well your stream is null because you are giving id instead of  position. use this one

```
mCard.get(position).getIcon()
```